# Testing directive for data with ControllerAs and Ng-Show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the ng-show condition inside my angular directive, which is using the controllerAs syntax and loading an external html file for the template.

I can't figure out how to test whether or not things are showing up in the template when a condition is met.

My question is this- How do I test that ng-show is working when conditions are met **and** the relevant data is being displayed in `ctrl.error` via the `<p>` tag?

Below are the relevant files:
Template File:

```
<!-- dataDisplay.html -->
<div>
    <div ng-show="!ctrl.eventsFound">
        <p id="errorMessage" style="color: red;">{{ctrl.error}}</p>
    </div>

    <div id="result" ng-show="ctrl.eventsFound">
        <section id="item-block" class="item-container">
            <div class="item-timeline-block" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items track by item.index">
                <div ng-class="item.iconBackground">
                    <span style="color:white" ng-class="item.iconImg"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="item-timeline-content">
                    <h2>{{::item.title}}</h2>
                    <span ng-show="{{::item.datetime}}" class="date">
                </span>
                    <p>{{::item.content}}</p>
                    <a ng-hide="{{!item.link}}" href="{{::item.link}}" target="_blank">Read more</a>
                    <small ng-hide="{{!item.link}}">{{::item.linkWarning}}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
<head>
    <title> Test </title>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <display-dir></display-dir>
</div>
</body>
<script src="node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="./path/displayDir.js"></script>
</html>
```

Directive:

```
//displayDir.js

angular.module('app', [])

    .directive('displayDir', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: 'dataDisplay.html',
            link: function() {

            },

            controller: 'displayCtrl'
        }

    })

    .controller('displayCtrl', ['$window', function($window) {

        let ctrl = this;

        ctrl.items =
            [
                { event: "a", title: "title a", index: 0, datetime: "01/02/2016", content: "content 1" },
                { event: "b", title: "title b", index: 2,   datetime: "01/01/2016", content: "content 2", link: 'http://www.google.com'},
            ];

        try {

            if (!ctrl.items.length) {
                ctrl.eventsFound = false;
                ctrl.error = "there is no data present for the control";
            } else {

                ctrl.eventsFound = true;
                ctrl.items.map(function(item) {
                    if (item.title == "title b") {
                        item.link = item.content;
                        item.linkWarning = `Warning - This link will bring you to external content!`
                        item.content = ""
                    }

                    if (item.datetime == "") {
                        item.lastUpdated = ""
                    } else {
                        item.lastUpdated = $window.moment(item.datetime).fromNow()
                    }
                    return item;
                });
            }

        } catch (error) {
            ctrl.eventsFound = false;
            ctrl.error = error.message
        }

    }])
```

Karma Test Spec- Using `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor`

```
describe('the displayDir directive', function() {

    let element, scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('htmlTemplate'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        //define the controller
        scope = $rootScope;
        ctrl = $controller('displayCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        })
    }));

    describe('after loading template url', function() {

        beforeEach(inject(function($compile) {
            // bring in the templateUrl file
            element = angular.element('<display-dir></display-dir>');
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        }));

        it('should show the errorMessage div', function() {
            let messageDiv = element[0].querySelector("#errorMessage");
            expect(messageDiv).toBeDefined();
        });

        it('should show the errorMessage div with the text', function(){
            ctrl.events =[]
            ctrl.eventsFound = false;
            ctrl.errorMessage = 'There is no data present for the control'
            let messageDiv = element[0].querySelector("#errorMessage");
            //This does not show the text error message text inside the 'p' tag
            console.log("element",messageDiv)

          /* something like 
          expect(messageDiv.innerHTML()).toEqual('There is no data 
          present for the control');

          or 

          expect(ctrl.errorMessage).toEqual('There is no data present 
          for the control') 
          */
        })

    })

});
```

**EDIT**

After working with Nikolaj, I have the following tests:

```
// FAILS ON the second expect - messageDiv.text should equal...
it('should show the errorMessage div', function() {
    ctrl.events =[];
    ctrl.eventsFound= false;
    ctrl.errorMessage = 'There is no data'
    let messageDiv = angular.element(element[0].querySelector("#errorMessage"));
    expect(messageDiv.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBeFalsy();
    expect(messageDiv.text()).toEqual("There is no data")
});

// FAILS ON the first expect - messageDiv should be truthy
it('should not show the errorMessage div', function() {
    ctrl.events = [{event: "test"}]
    ctrl.eventsFound= true;
    ctrl.errorMessage = ''
    let messageDiv = angular.element(element[0].querySelector("#errorMessage"));
    expect(messageDiv.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(messageDiv.text()).toEqual('')
});
```

[image]
**EDIT**

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MMBkynjc9lkAtpiVgUfa) of the behavior I am seeing. `scope.$digest()` doesn't appear to help, unless I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All `ng-show` basically does, is add the class `ng-hide` to the element, if the expression passed to the directive resolves to `false`. If we ignore animations, this css class is pretty much equivalent to this:

```
.ng-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

So to test whether the ng-show/ng-hide directives work, you can test whether the element contains the class `ng-hide`. Something like this:

```
it('should show the errorMessage div', function() {
    const messageDiv = angular.element(element[0].querySelector("#errorMessage"));
    expect(messageDiv.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBeFalse();
});
```

or to test whether the error message is hidden:

```
it('should not show the errorMessage div', function() {
    const messageDiv = angular.element(element[0].querySelector("#errorMessage"));
    expect(messageDiv.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBeTrue();
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikolaj. Thanks for the response. I was wondering how to get the innerHTML of the errorMessage div, once it was shown or hidden based on the conditions. So, once the conditions were met, I am expecting the text 'there is no data present...' once inside the div. Does that make sense? I will edit my post for clarity

Comment: You can call `messageDiv.text()` (assuming you've wrapped the element in `angular.element()` or similar as in my example above) to get the text within that element. That would return the text within the `<p>`-element, even if the element is hidden.

Comment: Ok. I think we are on the same page with that. However, I want to test to make sure that if `ctrl.eventsFound = false`;, then the `errorMessage` div is displayed AND the `errorMessage` text is displayed in `{{ctrl.error}}`. I am not getting that. I updated my question to show the example.

Comment: The values you assign your `ctrl.eventsFound` and `ctrl.errorMessage` properties havn't been bound to the DOM yet when you call `expect()`. Try calling `scope.$digest();` before querying the DOM. If that throws errors, it would be easier to help you if you could provide a plunker with the example to play around in.

Comment: I updated the question with a plunker. I tried `scope.$digest()` but it didnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Fixed my broken plunker link, it should now properly direct to the page

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [angular-test-runner](https://github.com/Pragmatists/angular-test-runner) library which allows better and easier testing AngularJS applications including html templates.

Your test will be quite simple and without any `magic class` assertions:

```
describe('the displayDir directive', () => {
    let app;
    const {expectElement} = testRunner.actions;

    beforeEach(() => {
        app = testRunner.app(['app', 'htmlTemplate']);
    });

    it('should show the errorMessage div', () => {
        const html = app.runHtml('<display-dir></display-dir>');

        html.verify(
            expectElement('#errorMessage').toExist()
        );
    });

});
```

Comment: I see that makes for a cleaner way of testing. I will check it out. However, it doesn't seem to take account for the scope change which is not happening. My test reads the initial scope/state from the controller, but then in the test, you can't change it and see the expected results after a change (errorMessage present, and hidden attribute from css)

Comment: You can e.g pass it to directive as a parameter and then you can test it easilly with angular-test-runner. For me changing values on scope in tests is part of bad design because probably you want to test your component for different inputs but not changing his internal state.